# Finding mean and variance of the circumference of a circle.

Tags: statistics, circles

I was tasked with solving the following problem.

> Suppose that we draw a circle whose radius $R$ is uniformly
> distributed on the interval $(0, 1)$. Find the mean and variance of
> the circumference of the circle.

I've seen a similar problem in which you are asked to find the mean and variance of the area of the circle, but I have not seen anyone calculate them for the circumference. I'm not really sure how I should approach this.

I've started by stating that the PDF of $R$ is $f_{R}(x)=1$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$, but I'm not sure if this is where I should start, or if that's even correct. Any hints/help is welcome, and much appreciated!

Comment: What is the circumference of a circle with radius $R$?

Comment: What did you learn by seeing the answer to a similar problem for area of a circle?  What would you learn by seeing the answer to this particular problem that involves cicumference? If the answer is "nothing" to the first question, why would the answer be different for the second?

Answer (score 2):

This should really be a comment, but I still don't have enough reputation.

The way you should think about this problem is that the circumference is going to be a function of the radius, $R$, as StubbornAtom suggested in the comments. Once you are able to determine what this function is, you can turn to general properties of expectation and variance to finish pretty quickly (at least in this situation). In particular, you should recall the mean and variance of $R \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$ and how constants affect mean and variance.

You can also do this explicitly with an integral. If you are still stuck, feel free to follow up.